# How to properly toggle UITableViewCell's accesoryType on cell selection/deselection?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to toggle **accesoryType** when a table cell is selected/deselected... the behavior should be: tap -> set accessoryType to **UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark** -> tap the cell again -> rollback to **UITableViewCellAccessoryNone** type.
The implementation in my controller is the following:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
```

...anyway once the style is configured as **UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark** I'm unable to restore it back to **UITableViewCellAccessoryNone**!
I also tried to call:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

but does not remove the checkmark... what should I do?

**EDIT: The implementation is ok, the problem was in the custom UITableViewCell subclass... sorry :P**

Answer (score 13):

Try this if this is what you want

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {   
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
    }
```

Comment: For the quick and dirty: `cell.accessoryType ^= UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have only one row as checkmark use this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryNone : UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    if (_lastSelectedIndexPath != nil)
    {
        UITableViewCell *lastSelectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_lastSelectedIndexPath];
        lastSelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    _lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tapping the cell again equates to selection of the cell and not deselection.

You need to have a toggle in the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method to check if the `cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    [theTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[theTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        // Reflect selection in data model
    } else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        // Reflect deselection in data model
    }
}
```